# How to apply style classes to td elements?

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to find out is the proper syntax to apply some style to each individual `td` in my table below:

```html
<section id="shows">
<!-- HTML5 section tag for the shows 'section' -->

<h2 class="gig">Shows</h2>

<ul class="gig">

    <!-- Start the table -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <!-- Setup the header row -->
            <th>When</th>
            <th>Where</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>Finish</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            // some PHP to fetch all the gig entries from the shows table
            $shows_query = "SELECT * FROM shows ORDER BY date ASC";
            $shows = mysql_query($shows_query);
            // a loop to place all the values in the appropriate table cells
            while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($shows)){
            //begin the loop...
            ?>

        <!-- Start the row -->
        <tr>

            <!-- Format the date value from the database and print it: -->
            <td class="when"><?php 
            $date = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($show['date'])); 
            echo "$date";
            ?></td>

            <td class="venue"><?php
            echo $show['venue'];
            ?></td>

            <!-- Format the start and end times and print them: -->
            <td class="start"><?php
            $time = date("G:i", strtotime($show['time'])); 
            echo "$time";
            ?></td>

            <td class="finish"><?php
            $until = date("G:i", strtotime($show['until']));
            echo "$until";
            ?></td>

            <!-- Finish this row -->
        </tr>

        <!-- Some space before the next row -->
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php 
            // close the loop:
             }
             ?>
        <!-- Finish the table -->
    </table>
</ul>

</section>
```

The styling that I have at the moment is:

```css
#shows table.gig { font-size: 25px; }
#shows td.finish { margin-left: 50px;}
```

I did have a class for the table itself but not sure if it's necessary.

The font-size works but what I can't figure out is how to apply the style to the `td`, `th`, `tr` elements etc. I have tried several things but can't seem to get it to work!

Comment: If your question relates to php, the posted code is fine. If it relates to css/html, please show the *rendered* html as seen by the browser: the `<?php ... ?>` server side scripts are irrelevant to CSS.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Give the table a class name and then you target the `td`'s with the following:

```css
table.classname td {
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, that works great for the font but for some reason I can't get the columns to space themselves out more using `margin-left` on the th or td elements.

Comment: @moleculezz Not sure if you still come on here but if so why use class instead of id?

Comment: @Ryan Best practice suggests to use classname instead of ID's. Search the net and you will find lots of information about it.

Answer (score 9):

If I remember well, some CSS properties you apply to `table` are not inherited as expected. So you should indeed apply the style directly to `td`,`tr` and `th` elements.

If you need to add styling to each column, use the `<col>` element in your table.

See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/xkuRA/2/

NB: You can't have a `margin` in a `td`. Use `padding` instead.

Comment: Hi, shows is the name of the overall class that the table is inside, the `#` were stripped out by the site so it should begin the line with that symbol.

Comment: This is more a comment than answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```css
table tr td.classname
{
 text-align:right;
 padding-right:18%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `:first-child`, `:nth-child(N)` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes.

They match elements based on their position in a group of siblings. In your case:

```css
table td:first-child  { /* 1st element */ }
table td:nth-child(2) { /* 2nd element */ }
table td:nth-child(3) { /* 3rd element */ }
table td:last-child   { /* 4th element */ }
```

Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Answer (score 3):

A more definite way to target a td is `table tr td { }`

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, I learnt a lot from it, I found out that cellspacing was the way to go but it seems you can only add that to the table declaration itself and not in the css file?

Comment: Yes, because `cellspacing` is an HTML attribute, not a CSS property. But you should be able to achieve what you want using CSS (see border-collapse, border-spacing...).

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a Class Name and define your style there like this :

```
table.tdfont td {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using with a reactive bootstrap table, i did not find that the

```
table.classname td {
```

syntax worked as there was no `<table>` tag at all.  Often modules like this don't use the outer tag but just dive right in maybe using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` for grouping at most.

Simply specifying like this worked great though

```
td.classname {
    max-width: 500px;
    text-overflow: initial;
    white-space: wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

as it directly overrides the `<td>` and can be used only on the elements you want to change.  Maybe in your case use

```
thead.medium td {
  font-size: 40px; 
}
tbody.small td {
  font-size:25px;
}
```

for consistent font sizing with a bigger header.